# Exception working with Service and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement a Service into my app. The service runs cyclic and downloads a .xml file wich gets parsed afterwards. Some values of the .xml file get added to an ArrayList. At the end both ArrayList are saved to SharedPreferences. When I receive a Broadcats onReceive() in my MainActivity the ArrayLists are "rebuild".

Thats the code of my Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    List<Float> arrayGraph = new ArrayList<Float>();
    List<Long> arrayGraph_time = new ArrayList<Long>();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // code to downlaod the file and parse it afterwards, already double checkd if it is working 
        // saving both ArrayLists to SharedPreferences

        Intent finished = new Intent("myPackage.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
        sendBroadcast(finished);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code to download file and parse it:

```
try {

    FTPFile choice;

    //new ftp client
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

    //try to connect
    String url =  "url"
    String user = "username"
    String pass = "password"
    String nr = "nr"

    ftp.connect(url);

    //login to server
    if (!ftp.login(user, pass)) {
        ftp.logout();
    }

    int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    //FTPReply stores a set of constants for FTP reply codes.
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
    }

    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("ftp");

    FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();

    //get newest .xml file name from ftp server
    Date lastMod = ftpFiles[0].getTimestamp().getTime();
    choice = ftpFiles[0];

    for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {

        if (file.getName().startsWith(nr)) {
            if (file.getTimestamp().getTime().after(lastMod)) {
                choice = file;
                lastMod = file.getTimestamp().getTime();
             }
         }
     }

     //get output stream
     OutputStream output;
     output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/path/" + choice.getName());

      //get the file from the remote system
      ftp.retrieveFile(choice.getName(), output);

      //close output stream
      output.close();

      ftp.logout();
      ftp.disconnect();

      File fXmlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/path/" + choice.getName());

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

      NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("PV");

          for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

              Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    int object = Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("Object"));
                    String t = eElement.getAttribute("t");
                    String value = eElement.getAttribute("Value");

                    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
                    Number number = format.parse(value);
                    float x = number.floatValue();

                    if (object == 0000) {
                        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(t);
                        // get milliseconds from date
                        long millisec = date.getTime();
                        // add time to ArrayList
                        arrayGraph_time.add(millisec);
                    } else if (object != 1000 && object != 1001 && object != 1002 && object != 1003 && object != 1004){
                        // add float value to ArrayList
                        arrayGraph.add(x);
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Code to save one ArrayList to SharedPreferences (same for the second):

```
SharedPreferences sp_arrayGraph = getSharedPreferences(name + "_arrayGraph", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp_arrayGraph.edit();

int listSize = arrayGraph.size();
editor.putInt("arrayGraph_size", listSize);

for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {

    float temp = arrayGraph.get(j);
    editor.putFloat("temp_" + j, temp);
}
editor.commit();
```

In my MainActivity I have created a BroadcastReceiver:

```
private ResponseReceiver receiver;

public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "myPackge.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // call method to update UI and set a notification if needed
    }
}
```

The BroadcastReceiver gets registered/unregistered in the onResume()/onPause() methods:

```
@Override    
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

The Service gets started in the onCreate() method of my MainActivity (To run my Service cyclic I used an AlarmManager):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent  intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pintent);

    startService(intent);
```

The Service is registered in my AndroidManifest file like so:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService">
</service>
```

Now when I run it on the ADV there is the following exception.

```
03-09 13:40:36.082    2276-2276/myPackage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=myPackage.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE flg=0x10 } in myPackage.MainActivity$ResponseReceiver@40e00418
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
            at myPackage.MainActivity.readArray(MainActivity.java:650)
            at myPackage.MainActivity$ResponseReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:315)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:758)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So it seems like there are no values added to my ArrayList. readArray() is my method to e.g. get the last value of ArrayList by `arraylist.get(arraylist.size() - 1)`

I know its a long question but hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found where the problem occured! I was executing a network operation in the main thread. Even in a Service this seems not to be allowed. So using the build in debugger of Android Studio I found that there was a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I moved my network code in a AsyncTask, now it works!

Thanks for the effort Hamid Shatu and Sachin Shelke.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log showing...

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
```

Which means, your `ArrayList's` length is `0` but you are trying to retrieve last index value by reducing `1` from the list size which results `index=-1`. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is produced when you try to get a of such index which doesn't exist.

So, Before retrieving value from `ArrayList` check that your list contains value as below...

```
if (arraylist.size() > 0) {

    arraylist.get(arraylist.size() - 1);

}
```

Comment: But there should be at least one value in "ArrayList 1" and 16 in the second ArrayList if the code in my Service was executed once. I already checked if that code works using Eclipse and printing out the array values.

Comment: see my updated answer...you could check that your list contains those value but when you want to retrieve them, you should check then also.

Comment: I have just updated my first post. **There has to something wrong with my code for downloading and parsing the file (also added).** When I add some values to the ArrayLists manualy (without getting them from the file) it works. No ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Not at all. I am using debuger now to find the problem. For some reason the code to download the file and parse it gets skipped?!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things which visible from mentioned code.

- You have to mention your service name in manifest file
- if you are received any data in receiver then you should send that through service.

For Example

```
 Intent finished = new Intent("myPackage.DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
 finished.putExtra("Key","Value");
 sendBroadcast(finished);
```

then in receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent!=null && intent.hasExtra("key"))
    {
         Object obj = intent.getExtra("key");
        // now put this obj in your arraylist
        // call method to update UI and set a notification if needed
    }


}
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I saved the ArrayList to SharedPreferences. Why should I send data then?

Comment: where you saved data in arraylist? Didn't see that code. Post your code for better solution. :)

Comment: When I add data to the ArrayList "manualy" it works. But the code to download the file and parse it already worked when i executed in Eclipse. Strange thing! Btw. I added the code to download and parse/add to ArrayList to the initial post.